# Python hangs when executing a shell script that runs a process as a daemon

Tags: python, python-2.7, daemon

I am trying to use `os.system` (soon to be replaced with `subprocess`) to call a shell script (which runs a process as a daemon)

```
os.system('/path/to/shell_script.sh')
```

The shell script looks like:

```
nohup /path/to/program &
```

If I execute this shell script in my local environment, I have to hit enter before being returned to the console as the shell script is running a process as a daemon.  If I do the above command in python, I also have to hit enter before being returned to the console.

However, if I do this in a python program, it just hangs forever.

How can I get the python program to resume execution after calling a shell script that runs a process as a daemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) -

> Within a script, running a command in the background with an ampersand (&)
>   may cause the script to hang until ENTER is hit. This seems to occur with
>   commands that write to stdout.

You should try redirecting your output to some file (or null if you do not need it), maybe `/dev/null` , if you really do not need the output.

```
 nohup /path/to/program > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Hi Anand, nohup by default writes to nohup.out (unless you redirect it). However I tried the following: `nohup /path/to/program > nohup.out &` and also `nohup /path/to/program & > nohup.out` but both required that I hit `enter` in both the bash and in python.

Comment: However, when run in my python program, it doesn't hang any more, thanks! Any idea on the discrepancy?

Comment: Sorry , maybe you should have tried to redirect both stout and stderr

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you trying using a separate thread?
Wrap up your process into something like

```
def run(my_arg):
    my_process(my_arg)

thread = Thread(target = run, args = (my_arg, ))
thread.start()
```

Checkout join and lock for more control over the thread execution.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html